# Добавить элемент в select с помощью jQuery

Tags: jquery, select

Нашёл вроде в интернете, но не работает:

```
$("#sel").append( $('<option value="1">qqq</option>') );
```

Как добавить элемент в select с помощью jQuery?

Answer (score 1):

[@sitev_ru](/users/18326/sitev_ru), даже так, как у вас - [будет добавлять](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/VD7mt/), хотя [не обязательно](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/VD7mt/1/) передавать элемент, как jQuery-объект.